# Android Gradle - Check which task is being executed

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In my gradle file I want to know which task triggered the code block. e.g. If I run

```
gradle assembleVanillaDebug
```

from the terminal, I want to know in my gradle file that assembleVanillaDebug task is being executed. This will also help me in figuring out I am running debug build type task or release build type task.
Can we know which task is being executed?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the end,

```
gradle.startParameter.taskNames
```

proved to be my friend. `gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames()` would return you the list of all tasks being executed in current build.

e.g. For `gradle clean assembleVanillaDebug`, it will return you a list of tasks `clean` and `assembleVanillaDebug`.

Comment: If the name of the task was abbreviated when running the command, this would return the task name abbreviated as typed, e.g. : `gradle asVanDeb` will result `gradle.startParameter.taskNames` return `[asVanDeb]`. Is there a way to get the actual name of the task?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing this is still the first hit on google when you search for listing tasks, I thought I'd share the better way I found of getting all tasks that are being scheduled:

```
// Doc: Returns the tasks which are included in the execution plan.
// The tasks are returned in the order that they will be executed.
gradle.taskGraph.allTasks
```

As opposed to <strike>`gradle.startParameter`</strike> which is meant for finding out how gradle has been started, this gives you a list of actual task objects that gradle queues for execution.

##### Edit:

Make sure the graph is resolved before using it. It should be available when running a task action, for example in a `doFirst {}`, or try running your code in the `whenReady{}` closure like so:

```
project.gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    println(project.gradle.taskGraph.allTasks)
}
```

Comment: Gradle sync fails with `Task information is not available, as this task execution graph has not been populated` when I try to use `gradle.taskGraph.allTasks`

Comment: @NolanAmy This is correct, you have to wait for the taskGraph to be resolved before you can use it. I've expanded my answer to better explain how you can access it after it has been populated